# Flask's order of rendering functions?

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to set up a basic website to practice Flask and have the following in my `app.py` file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "Hello, world!"


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(
        host="0.0.0.0",
        debug=True
    )
```

The contents of `home.html` are:

```
<div id="menubar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I noticed that when I run the app as `python app.py`, `Hello, world!` is printed onto the screen but not `home.html`. When I comment out the `hello_world` function, then the contents of `home.html` are rendered.

Why is this? Is there some sort of rendering order that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Flask takes the first matching route.

Comment: @KlausD. If I wanted to run both functions, what would I have to do? Would I have to change the rule in the decorator?

Comment: What do you mean by you want to do both? Do you want to have the browser display "Hello world", or render the template? Do you want them above and below, or on top, or how? You could put "Hello world" in the template maybe? Or you could `return "Hello world " + render_template('home.html')`

Comment: Either way, you can only sensibly have a single function with a route of `"/"`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I was hoping to be able to display the `"Hello, world!"` message along with rendering the `home.html` template. It seems like I would have to either configure the location of `home.html` or change the route rule. Is that correct?

Comment: I think you have a good answer from @Rob now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each route must be defined in the `@app.route()` decorator, the function names can be whatever you want them to be. If you want two different pages, your `app.py` could look like this:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/hello_world')  # this is http://0.0.0.0:5000/hello_world
def hello_world():
    return "Hello, world!"


@app.route('/')  # this is http://0.0.0.0:5000
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

If you want to *pass* the string `Hello, world` to `home.html`, your `app.py` could look like this:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')  # this is http://0.0.0.0:5000
def home():
    msg = "Hello, world!"
    return render_template('home.html', msg=msg)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

And your `home.html` could look like this:

```html
<div id="menubar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
```

Comment: I don't think you're misinterpreting it; I just think my question was a little vague to start with probably due to my lack of web dev knowledge. As per the comment on the question, am I only allowed to have one function that routes to `'/'`?

Comment: Yes, only one function can route to `'/'` for each type of method (GET, POST, PUT, etc). In your original code, the `'/'` route returns `Hello, world!` and that's it. Flask doesn't go back to look for additional functions that use the same route afterward returning something. I'll edit my answer to include some more info